# How do I permanently hide the debug console in VS Code?

Tags: console, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would like to configure my **Debug-Console**, so that it stops opening  automatically each, and every time, I run my code. FYI, I am writing  **C#**, and using the *OmniSharp C#* extension.

Comment: Have you tried ctrl + (backtick)

Comment: I need a permanent solution.

Comment: Ah okay it will always open when you run your debugger and you can close it whenever you want.

Comment: Which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: Ok sorry then your question didn’t specify that

Comment: I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Configure the Debug Console to Stop Auto-Opening

> ###### *"To configure the Debug Console so that it doesn't open automatically when you run your code, you will need to correctly configure the following setting:* `debug.internalConsoleOptions` *by assigning the the string value* `"neverOpen"` *to it. The code snippet below demonstrates the correct configuration for disabling the Debug Console's *Auto Open On Run* feature."*
>
> ---

```
    // ".../.vscode/settings.json"

    {
        "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
```

##### Add the Setting to one of your *`settings.json`* files

> ###### *"The configuration shown above can be configured in the user, or workspace settings.json file. Another option users have is to configure it via the V.S. Code GUI settings menu. The Settings Keyboard Shortcut, for opening the menu is shown below."*
>
> **Settings Menu Keybinding: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  <kbd>,</kbd>**
>
> ---

#### EDIT:

###### (Edited the paragraph below)

##### Best Practices for Testing New Configurations:

> ###### *"Its considered a good practice to always try a configuration for the first time in the workspace `settings.json` because the user `settings.json` file can be overridden by extensions. which can cause  confusing results when testing new configurations. This is a Debug setting, so you need to go another step further, because launch.json is top level for debug settings, therefore you need to also add the setting to your launch.json file."*
>
> ---

[See this link to see what I am talking about](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47249)

#### I don't write C#, but it should look something like this:

(and I bet you will find it there already, overriding your settings.json file)

```
{
  "name": "Run_Nodejs_Debugger",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "./build/index.js",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen" // ADD IT HERE!!!!
  "args": [""]
}
```

Comment: @Epik Thank you for the +15. I'm guessing that means you were able to configure your Debug Console with the configuration I posted in the above answer.

Comment: Did not work, the debug console is still appearing.

Comment: Okay, well I am glad I asked then. Let me see what I can find out. One question though, is it opening when you debug, or when you run the program without the debugger?

Comment: I am assuming your debugging, which is semantically different from saying, "running my code". This means you need to have a launch.json configured. In the launch.json you can configure the console. Ill show you in the answer. This will fix your issue if you implement it correctly, infact its the cause of the issue really. (__Read Answer Above__)

Comment: Not only read the answer, but view the link I edited in, since the guy was using the C# debugger as well.